# Initialization of an EM4425 RFID Chip

Tags: initialization, rfid

I'm new here and hope someone can help me out.

I have some questions due to the initialization process of an EM4425 chip. There are different versions of the chip. V10 is preset by EM and the configuration is permalocked. In this case, is it possible to write data on the chip on every memory bank also the HF memory? This would be the prefered way we want to go. Otherwise we have to do the initialization process by ourselves to ensure the writeability on every memory bank.

We wanted to order the V10, so that we don't have to initialize the tags by ourselves. But now, a supplier of us has told me, that we won't be able to write the NDEF message on the tag if we take the preset version. Now I want to ensure if this is correct.

I'm looking forward to your replies. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have the datasheet? There is a lot of details about the versions in there